# Combinatorics Chess Spot Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

[image: jordle]

Very tough problem, I must say.

**NOT CONSIDERING** the squares both can go in from one of the **black** square not considering the squares both can go to. The horse can go to is:

$$4 + 4 = 8 \space \mathrm{possible \space squares.}$$

Then since there are $8$ squares each is:

$$8*8 = 64 \space \text{possible squares from any black square}$$

$8$ can go back to the ORIGINAL square. So thus far,

$$64 - 8 = 56$$

But I dont know what else to go?

Comment: Why are you subtracting 8, and not 7?  You want to count the original square once, don't you?

Comment: Although its not an elegant solution, with colored pencils/markers, it is rather easy to brute force a solution by mapping them all out (saving time and space by noticing that there is a great deal of symmetry involved) to arrive at a brute force solution of 33.  This approach will not work nearly as well if we were to ask about six+ moves into the future.

Comment: Out and back to the original square: $1.$ Two moves in the same direction: $8.$ Two noncollinear moves: $8\times6/2=24$ because there are two routes to the same destination square, making a parallelogram. Final answer: $1+8+24=33.$

Answer (score 0):

Think of a knight-move as a shift by $(\pm 1,\pm 2)$ or $(\pm 2,\pm 1)$ from the origin.  For a knight to end up at the same place, you need two ordered sums that give the same value.  So, I will call $(a,b)+(c,d)$ a sequence of two knight-moves.

1.) Consider the sequence of moves $(1,2)+(-1,-2)$ will take the knight back to the origin (and that is the only option.

2.) It is also true that $(1,2)+(1,-2)=(1,-2)+(1,2)$ so, inverting the order of the remaining 56 pairs of moves results in the same final position.

3.) Are there any other pairs of ordered sums which have the same final value?